# Numerical analysis Taylor's method question: Find a value of $n$ necessary for $P_n(x)$ to approximate $f(x)$ within $10^{-6}$ on $[-0.5,0.5]$.

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

Let $f(x)=\tan^{-1}(x)$

Let $P_n(x)$ be the $n$th Taylor polynomial for $f(x)$ about $x_0=0$

Find a value of $n$ necessary for $P_n(x)$ to approximate $f(x)$ within $10^{-6}$ on $[-0.5,0.5]$.

Is it the smalled possible value?

> My attempt:
>
> $f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^2+1}$
>
> $f''(x)=\dfrac{-2x}{(x^2+1)^2}$
>
> As I attempt to find $f^n(x)$, the expression gets even more complicated.
>
> So I try to evaluate the error term for $P_1(x)$.
>
> Which gets me to within $0.125$.
>
> And I am stuck

Comment: Hints would be nice thanks

Comment: As a starter, the Taylor series of $f$ can be calculated through the geometric series - that is $$f(x)=\int_0^x f'(x)dx=\int_0^x\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^x\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^{2n}dx$$ $$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}dx$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Taylor series for $\arctan x$ is 
$$x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^7}{7}+\cdots.$$

The easy way to find it is to integrate the series for $\frac{1}{1+t^2}=1-t^2+t^4-t^6+\cdots$ term by term, because
$$\arctan x=\int_0^x \frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt,$$
at least when $|x|\lt 1$. (It is acutally even correct at $x=\pm 1$.)

For numbers in our range, the series is an **alternating series**, and the error made by truncating at a particular place has absolute value less than the absolute value of the first "neglected" term.

This should be information enough to handle the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help sir.

Comment: You are welcome. One has to go a medium long way (at the worst $x=\pm 0.5$). I believe we have to go up to and including  the term $-\frac{x^{15}}{15}$. That gives us error about $4\times 10^{-7}$.

Comment: Since you used a bound rather than an equation, it's not obvious that the maximum error is at $\pm 0.5$ (although it is true in this case), or that smaller values of $n$ don't turn out have small enough error.

Comment: However, for an alternating series, the error made by truncating to $n$ terms is not only less than the absolute value of the $n+1$'th term, it is greater than
the absolute value of the $n+1$'th term minus the absolute value of the $n+2$'th term.

Comment: The error is in fact smaller than that, closer to $3\times 10^{-7}$. But cutting off at the $x^13/13$ term is not good enough.